# Option Select value to select all

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make option select for my page and I have added php in it so option will not change after submission but I want to add value=any so on selected item ANY it will select all from the database.

```
<option value="" selected>ANY</option>
    <option <?php if ($_GET['siz'] == '640 x 480') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="640 x 480">640x480</option>
  <option <?php if ($_GET['siz'] == '800 x 600') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="800 x 600">800x600</option>
   <option <?php if ($_GET['siz'] == '1024 x 768') { ?>selected="true" <?php }; ?>value="1024 x 768">1024x768</option>
</select>
```

**When "ANY" is selected it will show all the data from the database**

```
if(isset($_GET['siz'])){
$siz = $_GET['siz'];

// My Query

    SELECT * FROM data where size='$siz'
```

Now tell me what should I add in the `value="?"`

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can give value for `ANY` to anything as you like. For example,

```
<option value="any" selected>ANY</option>
```

and in the php file you have to check whether the selected one is `any` or not using the value of the option.

In this example do like,

```
if(isset($_GET['siz'])){
$siz = $_GET['siz'];

if($siz=='any')
{
    SELECT * FROM data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some ways to solve it:
Can dynamically make the sql request, the the "any" value will be none.
and

```
if(!$siz)
{
sql = "SELECT * FROM data;"
}
}
```

or you can change sql to

```
SELECT * FROM data where size in ($siz)
```

and "any" value will be:
' "640 x 480","800 x 600","1024 x 768" '